# Quasi-Isometry and finiteness

Tags: group-theory

Is finiteness a Quasi-Isometric invariant property?!
i.e.
Let $G$,$H$ be two groups which $G$ is finite and $G\sim_{QI} H$, is $H$ finite?!

Comment: Yes. Think of QI as "screwing up your eyes and zooming out" from the cayley graph. If your group is infinite then your graph is qi to a point. If it is infinite then it is bot qi to a point.

Comment: (this is not a proof. I just thought it was better than saying "yes, obviously"...)

Answer (score 4):

A f.g. group $G$ is quasi-isometric to the trivial group iff every $g\in G$ has bounded length (with respect to some generating set), i.e., iff $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Not much about groups. Among metric spaces, being bounded is a QI-invariant (it's even a coarse invariant). Actually, non-empty bounded metric spaces form a single QI-class.

For finitely generated groups, finite $\Leftrightarrow$ bounded.

(In the broader setting of compactly generated locally compact group, one rather have compact $\Leftrightarrow$ bounded, so being compact is QI-invariant but not being finite.)